# ErrorDocs | VirtualHost | Apache 2.2.x

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, errordocument

So, I'm having a challenge trying to get my virtual hosts (in the example, called bozo) to 'point' at the right  error documents for 401, 403,... errors. I am trying the following construct, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 <VirtualHost <ip.address.here>
  ServerAdmin my.name@email.com
  DocumentRoot /home/www/htdocs/virtual/bozo
  ServerName www.bozoclown.com
  ErrorLog logs/bozo_error_log

  ErrorDocument 401 errors/401.html
  ErrorDocument 404 errors/404.html
  ErrorDocument 403 errors/403.html
 </VirtualHost>
```

The custom error files 401.html, 403.html and so on are in the errors subdirectory, which is off the document root. If I point a browser at [www.bozoclown.com/errors/403.html](http://www.bozoclown.com/errors/403.html), the 403.html files comes up (so it, and the other error files, are there, and accessible). But, when I intentionally generate a 403 error accessing the virtual site, I'm not being sent to the custom 403 page. Instead, I'm getting the following error:

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

So, I try adding the following in the virtual host declaration:

```
<Directory "/home/www/htdocs/virtual/bozo/errors">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But that doesn't work.

Suggestions? Pointers to the obvious correction I need to make?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You gonna need to modify your configuration file a little, you need an `Alias` directive to map the `/errors` URL `path`, update the ErrorDocument to the URL `path` instead of the file path.

Here is the final file, after restarting the Apache server it should work

```
<VirtualHost <ip.address.here>>
  ServerAdmin my.name@email.com
  DocumentRoot /home/www/htdocs/virtual/bozo
  ServerName www.bozoclown.com
  ErrorLog logs/bozo_error_log

  Alias /errors "/home/www/htdocs/virtual/bozo/errors"
  <Directory "/home/www/htdocs/virtual/bozo/errors">
    Options -Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.html
  ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
  ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'll give that a try.